# atom started as root but can't access some folders in project

Tags: atom-editor

I am using the Atom text editor and I have this problem that even when I start it as root:

`sudo atom`

there are still files in the project I can't access.

To be more accurate, the problem is that I am trying to look for some strings in the project with the `Ctrl+Shift+f` combination and I get no results even when the string I am looking for is copied from one of the files in the project.

I will add that all these folders I don't have access to during my search, are colored in a different color (Dark grey in my case but that's obviously per theme).

Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried changing the setting for *Settings > Core Settings > Exclude VCS Ignored Paths*? This is checked by default, and the fuzzy finder will not show files that are ignored. From your description, it sounds like these files are ignored (and thus shown in a different colour).

More info here: https://discuss.atom.io/t/project-search-does-not-index-files-in-gitignore/2804

Here's a screenshot showing the box to uncheck:

[image: Atom Core Settings]